# How to define a family of structs with different const parameters in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, type-level-computation

I ran into this problem while reading the struct definitions for page tables (used in an operating system source code targeting x86_64 platform). The definitions are shown below:

```
pub trait TableLevel {}

pub enum Level4 {}
pub enum Level3 {}
pub enum Level2 {}
pub enum Level1 {}

impl TableLevel for Level4 {}
impl TableLevel for Level3 {}
impl TableLevel for Level2 {}
impl TableLevel for Level1 {}

pub trait HierarchicalLevel: TableLevel {
    type NextLevel: TableLevel;
}

impl HierarchicalLevel for Level4 {
    type NextLevel = Level3;
}

impl HierarchicalLevel for Level3 {
    type NextLevel = Level2;
}

impl HierarchicalLevel for Level2 {
    type NextLevel = Level1;
}
```

This piece of Rust code seems not very clever. I'm wondering if I can parameterize the level number, e.g. 1,2,3,4. With C++, I can achieve this easily:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned L>
struct Level {
    typedef Level<L-1> NextLevel;
};

template <>
struct Level<1> {};

int main() {
    // The output below will give "1".
    // It checks the type `Level<3>::NextLevel::NextLevel`
    // and the type `Level<2>::NextLevel` are indeed the same type.
    std::cout
        << std::is_same<Level<3>::NextLevel::NextLevel,
                        Level<2>::NextLevel>::value
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to do the same thing in Rust, but I couldn't because Rust wouldn't allow me do to arithmetic operations with constant parameters.

```
#![feature(min_const_generics)]

struct Level<const LEVEL: usize> {}
impl <const LEVEL: usize> TableLevel for Level<LEVEL> {}

impl <const LEVEL: usize> HierarchicalLevel for Level<LEVEL> {
    // Error message from the compiler:
    // generic parameters may not be used in const operations
    // cannot perform const operation using `LEVEL`
    // help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `LEVEL`
    type NextLevel = Level<{LEVEL - 1}>;
}
```

Is it possible to parameterize the level number in the current version (possibly nightly) of Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unstable language feature, [`min_const_generics`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2000) is quite limited in what it lets you do. As you discovered, you can't use expressions involving generic constants in type arguments.

However, in stable Rust, you can use the [`typenum`](https://docs.rs/typenum/1.12.0/typenum/) crate, which works in a similar way to what you were trying, but does all of the type-level boilerplate for you.

```
use std::ops::Sub;
use typenum::{Unsigned, U1, U2, U3}; // 1.12.0

struct Level<N: Unsigned>(N);

impl<N: Unsigned> Level<N> {
    fn value() -> usize {
        N::to_usize()
    }
}

trait HierarchicalLevel {
    type NextLevel;
}

impl<N> HierarchicalLevel for Level<N>
where
    N: Sub<U1> + Unsigned,
    <N as Sub<U1>>::Output: Unsigned,
{
    type NextLevel = Level<<N as Sub<U1>>::Output>;
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        <Level::<U3> as HierarchicalLevel>::NextLevel::value(),
        Level::<U2>::value()
    );
}
```

The types `U0`, `U1`, `U2`,... represent the unsigned integers 0, 1, 2,...